# Alternate Way to Find Integers in Range of given Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

I encountered this question recently where 
$$f(x)=\int_0^{x} {e^{t}\sin(x-t)}$$
and 
$$g(x)=\dfrac{d^{2}f(x)}{dx^{2}} - f(x)$$
I had to find the number of integers in the range of $~g(x)~$

I solved it analytically by computing it's second derivative after substituting $$x=x-t$$ and computing the function $~g(x)~$ which came out to be $\sin x+\cos x$.

However I was wondering is there a way to do this without actually computing the derivative and using some sort of numerical analysis or such technique to check for Integers in the range without using any significant computation power.

Comment: Not clear: you want the number of integers in the range of $g$ or in the range of $f$?

Comment: @uniquesolution g I'll update the question

Comment: @StackUpPhysics Hi, this is a really interesting question, I wrote my proof below. Let's have a discussion if you have questions on this, ok?

Comment: @KevinSong Yeah that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that is possible. And I also found that your answer has a small problem.
$$f(x)=\int_0^{x} {e^{t}\sin(x-t)}=-e^{t}\cos(x-t)+e^t\cos(-t)$$
When we take the second derivative of $f(x)$, $e^t\cos(-t)$ becomes $0$. So we don't consider this constant until the end, because any vertical translation applied on the function will only translate its range.So, let $$y(x)=-e^{t}\cos(x-t)$$

Instead of calculating the $2^{nd}$ derivative, we use a general pattern for this kind of trigonometric functions: **Its $2^{nd}$ derivative is equal to $-f(x)$** (Note that I didn't calculate it)

Hence, $g(x)=-2y(x)-C$ where $C=e^t\cos(-t)$, but please ignore $C$.

Now, found that any stationary point of $y(x)$ appear when $\cos(x-t)$ reaches its minimum or maximum. Therefore, we require:
$$x-t=k\pi, k\in\mathbb{N}$$
Since $y(x)$ is periodic, we only need to investigate one pair of points, then $x=k\pi+t$, plug this result in $y(x)$ you'll get:
$$y(k\pi+t)=-e^{t}\cos(k\pi)$$
Apply $-2y(x)$, The number of integers:$$N=\lfloor|2e^{t}\cos(k\pi)|-C\rfloor+|\lceil-|2e^{t}\cos(k\pi)|-C\rceil |+1$$
The reason for $+1$ is that we need to count $0$.

Comment: Nice answer thanks a lot for sharing this

Comment: The problem you mention does it make the process incorrect and coincidentally I get the correct answer or is it a problem if we try a different approach?

Comment: @StackUpPhysics Your answer ($\sin x+\cos x$) changes when x changes, if you plug in $x=1$, you won't get an integer. I think your process is correct, but I'm not sure if you did an incorrect calculation.

Comment: @StackUpPhysics Just think about that function: $\cos (x-t)$ only control its period. The stretch factor $e^t$ control its range, actually, so the final result should not be a function of $x$, but should be a function of $t$.

Comment: @StackUpPhysics I just edited one error made in my answer.